# No response from Jquery validation when creating Meteor account

Tags: meteor

Basically, I'm using Jquery validation package as a way to alert errors to users when creating and registering accounts on Meteor, since the boilerplate interface doesn't work in my case.

Anyway, when a user tries to sign up for an account, I get no response at all on client. The user is just created with no message or redirection like it's supposed to have.

Here is the particular code:

```
Template.createAccount.onRendered(function(){
  var validator = $('.register').validate({
    submitHandler: function(){
      user = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
      };

  Accounts.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    function(error){
      if(error){
        if(error.reason == "Email already exists."){
         validator.showErrors({
             email: "The email belongs to a registered user."
         });
     }
      } else{
        console.log("Account successfully created.");
        Router.go("starter");
      }
    }
  });
    }
  });
})
```

I'm using the same code logic for account logins with the only exception being a different meteor accounts function (`Meteor.loginWithPassword()` for login and `Accounts.createUser()` for account creation).

No response at all, so it probably has to do something with the callback function, since the user account is created, but no message displayed on client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including your callback as part of your options object when it should be a separate argument. It should look more like this:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
}, function(error){
  if(error){
    if(error.reason == "Email already exists."){
     validator.showErrors({
         email: "The email belongs to a registered user."
     });
 }
  } else{
    console.log("Account successfully created.");
    Router.go("starter");
  }
});
```